# Remove/delete each minimum value in each row of a NxM matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, minimum, numpy-ndarray

Is it possible to remove/delete each minimum value in each row of a NxM matrix
creating a new matrix?

I´ve tried this so far without any luck:

```
for n in range(0,len(matrix_name)):
    Ma = grades.remove(np.min(matrix_name[n,:]))
```

and this too:

```
for n in range(0,len(matrix_name)):
    Ma = np.delete(matrix_name,np.min(matrix_name[n,:]))
```

Comment: Is this a NumPy matrix? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes, it is a numpy matrix.                                                                                              
I´ve tried np.delete, matrix_name.remove and matrix_name[n>np.matrix_name]

Comment: Do you want to remove exactly one value per row or all that equal the min val in that row? In the latter case, what format should the output have?

Comment: @CEFOG We kind of need to know the answer to the above question in order to remove the right number of values.  Are you trying to drop all 0's from the gradebook or just one of the ones tied for the lowest?

Comment: There is only one minimum value in each row(sorry I should have mentioned that). So I just need to remove one value

Comment: @CEFOG [Please consider accepting whichever answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) helped you the most.

Answer (score 1):

If reconstructing the desired result from the original array instead of modifying the original array by *deleting* the min values, is allowed then this approach should do the job:

```
# some test array
In [19]: arr
Out[19]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19]])

In [20]: r, c = arr.shape

# find the minimum along axis 1 (i.e. along rows)
In [21]: min_vals = np.min(arr, axis=1, keepdims=True)

# reshape the result to 2D array
In [22]: (arr[np.where(arr != min_vals)]).reshape(r, c-1)
Out[22]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [13, 14, 15],
       [17, 18, 19]])
```

Note: This approach assumes that there's only one minimum value in each row.

Answer (score 1):

If duplicates are not an issue or if deleting only one of them per row is acceptable:

```
m, n = a.shape
np.where(np.arange(n-1) < a.argmin(axis=1)[:, None], a[:, :-1], a[:, 1:])
```